# Portforwarding problems on Linksys WRT120N

Tags: networking, router

So i am trying to portforward a few ports, but i cant seem to get it work. I have done portforwarding before on other routers on different networks but this one doesnt seem to work at all. My router is linksys WRT120N. What could be a possible error?

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell what is going on because the question is very vague, but the vast majority of port forwarding problems are a typo in the forwarded ip. You might also want to try selecting udp/tcp instead of just one type of port (although tcp is much more common). Please elaborate on what problems you're having.

Comment: Okay, i figured out that my isp is somehow blocking portforwarding. i confirmed this by calling them. any workarounds?

Comment: I don't know, but that seems very strange to me. What isp are you using and where are you?

Comment: If all else fails, I know there a service that let's you Tunnel a port to their server so that instead of doing yourip:port it would be user.server.com:port but I can't find what it's called now.